# Click() is not working when executing with breakpoints. F10 mode in VS

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Normally the click() method is working but when i keep a breakpoint in code and press F10. The click does not happen. Kindly let me know why this happens.

Comment: The breakpoint is on the `Click()` line or one line before?

Comment: I tried keeping breakpoints on the click and a line before it. Both cases , it is not clicking.

Comment: You need to press F10 one more time when this line is highlighted.

Comment: Ya done that. Executed. Issue is in website, element is not getting clicked.

Comment: try Actions class click or Javascript click and see if it receives click command

Comment: Tried both, it is not clicking.

Comment: When executing normally without breakpoints it is working..only when executing in F10 mode, problem occurs. So i am unable to debug my script.